# How to change a control's name?

Tags: qt, controls

It's probably obvious but I'm having problems with it. How do I change in Qt a control's name? I.e. I created a few controls (buttons/edits/etc...) in Qt Creator and they have some default names (e.g. pushButton_2, lineEdit) that I want to change to different ones that actually tell me what they're for. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in QtCreator's designer in several ways:

- select a control in a top half of object editor, press `F2`, edit name, press `Enter`
- double click a control in a top half of object editor (column `Object`), than edit name and press `Enter`;
- select a control, find tag `objectName` in a bottom half of object editor, select it and click on `Value` column, edit name and press `Enter`.

Comment: (1) Selecting a control (in the designing window) and pressing F2 usually changes it's caption, not name. (2) The other 2 methods seem to change its name but in code I still can't use the new names, why??

Comment: The first one works differently with different controls - my bad (removed this one, added another). About new names - have you saved changes? You need to press `Ctrl+s` or close file and accept saving changes.

Comment: Not only did I save them, I actually restarted Qt Creator and tried anything else that came to my mind - nothing worked. :/

Comment: Open Tools->Options->Embedding of the UI Class. If one of first two (aggregation) is selected, then you'll have to access your controls via `ui` object like this: `ui->pushButton`. If you want direct access - change it to 'Multiple inheritance' and recreate all widgets (including MainWindow).

Comment: I know I have to acces them via `ui` which I do. It's just that `ui` never seems to update its fields' names' values.

Comment: Okey, that is strange. Does your project compiles when using renamed components in code?

Comment: Can't say, I'm only using Creator to create UI, coding and compiling is done in VS.

Comment: You can create ui with Qt's `designer` program without installing QtCreator. I've never used qt in vs, but will give you two more advices: try to rebuild your project completely, if it does not help - try to generate "ui_*.h" files, using Qt's `ui` program manually.